# Cutting string into different types of variables

Tags: bash

Full script:

```
snapshot_details=`az snapshot show -n $snapshot_name -g $resource_group --query \[diskSizeGb,location,tags\] -o json`
echo $snapshot_details
IFS='",][' read -r -a array <<< $snapshot_details
echo ${array[@]}
IFS=' ' read -r -a array1 <<< ${array[@]}
echo ${array1[0]} #size
echo ${array1[1]} #location
```

How can I break this into 3 different variables:

```
a=5

b=eastus2

c={ "name": "20190912123307" "namespace": "aj-ssd" "pvc": "poc-ssd" }
```

and is there any easier way to parse `c` so that I can easy traverse over all the keys and values?

o/p of the above script is:

```
[ 5, "eastus2", { "name": "20190912123307", "namespace": "ajain-ssd", "pvc": "azure-poc-ssd" } ]
5 eastus2 { name : 20190912123307 namespace : ajain-ssd pvc : azure-poc-ssd }
5
eastus2
```

Comment: I doubt that Bash is the right tool for this. Are you open to using a more-complete programming language, such as Perl?

Comment: I wish I could.

Comment: Are you sure? If it will always be the same: `a=5; b=eastus2; c='{ "name": "20190912123307" "namespace": "aj-ssd" "pvc": "poc-ssd" }'` ;-)

Comment: "I wish I could." Why can't you? What are your constraints?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It will not be nice in Bash, but this should work if your input format does not vary (including no `{`, `}` or spaces inside the key/value pairs):

```
S='5 "eastus2" { "name": "20190912123307" "namespace": "aj-ssd" "pvc": "poc-ssd" }'
a=`echo "$S" | awk '{print $1}'`
b=`echo "$S" | awk '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/\"//g'`
c=`echo "$S" | awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'`
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
echo "$c"
elems=`echo "$c" | sed -e 's/{//' | sed -e 's/}//' | sed -e 's/: //g'`
echo $elems
for e in $elems
do
    kv=`echo "$e" | sed -e 's/\"\"/ /' | sed -e 's/\"//g'`
    key=`echo "$kv" | awk '{print $1}'`
    value=`echo "$kv" | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo "key:$key; value:$value"
done
```

The idea in the iteration over key/value pairs is to:

(1) remove the space (and colon) between keys and corresponding value so that each key/value pair appears as one item.

(2) inside the loop, change the delimiter between keys and values (which is now `""`) to space and remove the double quotes (variable 'kv').

(3) extract the key/value as the first/second item of `kv`.

EDIT:
Avoid file name wildcard expansions.

Comment: This is *very* buggy -- if you had, say, `name='foo * bar'`, you'd get the `*` replaced with a list of filenames in the current directories by all the unquoted expansions, not to mention all the assumptions the code makes about structure and ordering.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is not necessarily buggy since it gives the requested output. You are correct that it is not very robust to special characters and changes in the input format, which I also state myself in the answer. As I understand this is in agreement with the assumptions of the question.

Comment: Surely you don't expect this to only ever be used with the *exact* string `5 "eastus2" { "name": "20190912123307" "namespace": "aj-ssd" "pvc": "poc-ssd" }`? Order of printing values in a dict is often undefined, meaning that there's no guarantee that subsequent calls will put `name`, `namespace` and `pvc` in the same order; and robust code would check that it works for every name that AWS (assuming that's the relevant domain) allows a host to have, if not for every possible JSON literal.

Answer (score 1):

A JSON parser, such as `jq`, should **always** be used when splitting out items from a JSON array in bash. Line-oriented tools (such as `awk`) are unable to correctly escape JSON -- if you had a value with a tab, newline, or literal quote, it would be emitted incorrectly.

Consider the following code, runnable exactly as-is even by people not having your `az` command:

```
snapshot_details_json='[ 5, "eastus2", { "name": "20190912123307", "namespace": "ajain-ssd", "pvc": "azure-poc-ssd" } ]'
{ read -r diskSizeGb && read -r location && read -r tags; } < <(jq -cr '.[]' <<<"$snapshot_details_json")

# show that we really got the content
echo "diskSizeGb=$diskSizeGb"
echo "location=$location"
echo "tags=$tags"
```

...which emits as output:

```
diskSizeGb=5
location=eastus2
tags={"name":"20190912123307","namespace":"ajain-ssd","pvc":"azure-poc-ssd"}
```

Comment: I think this answer shows a good solution and useful recommendation, but it is not an answer to the question. The OP input is not JSON and the OP does not mention JSON at all. Furthermore, this answer requires installation of the tool `jq`. The OP clarifies that e.g. using Perl is not an option, hence we must assume that only a Bash environment with standard tools is available.

Comment: @nielsen, the's original sample isn't JSON, but when they show an `echo` output from their actual command's invocation later in the question, you see that their *real* data *actually is* JSON, and they were simply mistyping it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Bash can do this with the awk command:

To extract the 5 :

```
awk -F " " '{ print $1 }'
```

To extract eastus2 :

```
awk -F "\"" '{ print $2 }'
```

To extract the last string :

```
awk -F "{" '{ print "{" $2 }'
```

As seen here :

[image]

To explain quickly

```
awk -F " " '{ print $1 }'
```

`-F` sets a delimiter, here we set space as the delimiter.
Then, we ask awk to print the first occurence before the first delimiter is hit.

The slightly more complex one:

```
awk -F "{" '{ print "{" $2 }'
```

Here we set `{` as the delimiter. Since we wouldn't have the bracket with only printing `$2`, we're also manually re-printing the bracket (`print "{" $2`)